# Problema fila com prioridade

Tags: java

Alguém me dá uma luz do que fazer pra resolver esse problema, eu não tenho ideia de como começar

> Escreva um programa que simule a distribuição de senhas de atendimento a um grupo de pessoas. Cada pessoa pode receber uma senha prioritária ou uma senha normal. O programa deve obedecer os seguintes critérios:
>
> - Existe apenas um atendente
> - 1 pessoa com senha normal deve ser atendida a cada 3 pessoas com senha prioritária
> - Não havendo prioridades, as pessoas com senha normal podem ser atendidas

Eu não to pedindo a resposta, quero apenas uma explicação do que tenho que fazer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você irá precisar de duas listas `FIFO` que em `Java` podem ser obtidas utilizando [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> [**FIFO**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)
>
> Em Ciência da Computação, FIFO (acrônimo para First In, First Out, que em português significa primeiro a entrar, primeiro a sair) refere-se a estruturas de dados do tipo fila.

```
LinkedList<String> normal = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<String> prioritaria = new LinkedList<>();
```

Após isso implemente os métodos para obter uma senha prioritária ou normal:

```
public String pegarSenhaNormal() {
  String senha = gerarSenha();

  normal.add(senha);
  return senha;
}

public String pegarSenhaPrioritaria() {
  String senha = gerarSenha();

  prioritaria.add(senha);
  return senha;
}
```

Mantenha um contador:

```
Integer contador = 0;
```

Implemente o método para chamar a próxima senha com a regra de fila vazia e contador após a terceira chamada:

```
public String chamarProximo() {
  LinkedList<String> fila;
  String senha;

  if (contador.equals(3) || prioritaria.isEmpty()) {
    fila = normal;
    contador = 0;
  } else {
    fila = prioritaria;
    contador++;
 }
  
  senha = fila.removeFirst();
  return senha;
}
```

Comment: @Tmc você aprovou uma alteração de código, percebe que isso somente o autor pode avaliar se está certo ou não? Evite aprovar esse tipo de edição, somente o autor pode decidir se é válido ou não.

Comment: @rLinhares você aprovou uma alteração de código, percebe que isso somente o autor pode avaliar se está certo ou não? Evite aprovar esse tipo de edição, somente o autor pode decidir se é válido ou não.

Comment: @Articuno faz sentido não poder aprovar edições de código, vou ter mais atenção